# How can I send and receive data concurrently in socket programming in java using multithread?

Tags: java, sockets, concurrency, datagram

I'm new to Java and trying to write a program using Datagram socket to send & receive packets between a client and a server. The problem is that when the cursor arrives at the `receive()` line, it gets stuck there until a packet arrives. During this time, how can I send data to the other side? In the other word, how can I have it send and receive concurrently using datagram socket?

Comment: When you want to do something concurrently and independently, you need to use multiple threads.

Comment: If you could share some code that would be helpful.

Answer (score 4):

You need **threads** (or NIO/netty, but that's much more advanced).

Basically blocking IO (as the name implies) blocks current thread on every read/write operation if it can't be handled at a time. Thus you need a second thread to handle writes. Every good Java socket tutorial will include an example of a multithreaded server.

Answer (score -1):

It seems you are referring to Asynchronous I/O, and although that is indeed achieved by using threads and sockets (as stated before), it is best done using NIO: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/New_I/O

It scales much better, and is event based, which is a much easier concept to grasp than multithreading, assuming you don't have much experience with IO and networking. And you can avoid some of its complexity by using Apache MINA: http://mina.apache.org/

Comment: You're conflating three different things here. Concurrent I/O uses multiple threads in blocking mode and is supported by the `java.net` package. Non-blocking I/O is supported by NIO and Netty. Asynchronous I/O uses completion callbacks, not threads, and was introduced in JDK 1.7 as NIO2.